# Recreating A Puzzle Effect Using Stencils

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, stencil, portals

I'm trying to recreate something I saw on reddit a while back. I tried rendering camera output onto planes, but am not getting the results that I want -- this is basically what I'm trying to recreate:

[image: Portal Cube]

I found [this](https://github.com/noisecrime/Unity-StencilPortalRoomCube) project on GitHub, which is similar, but definitely different as it's rendering stationary objects depending on the view (is that what I want to be doing?).

Here is what I have so far:

A cube with inward-facing planes, which has a sphere inside it:

[image: Inverse Cube Side]

An orthographic camera facing each inner wall:

[image: Portal Camera]

A cube with outward-facing planes:

[image: Cube]

Each cube face has a material on it:

[image: Material]

With a texture on it that reflects one of the camera's viewports:

[image]

I'm sure I need to do some kind of shader stencil work - and I don't have too much experience. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Unity-StencilPortalRoomCube](https://github.com/noisecrime/Unity-StencilPortalRoomCube) and [Impossible Geometry: Non-Euclidean Cubes](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/12/09/3873/)